# How to use gridstack-angular.js with Hot Towel Template

Tags: html, angularjs, hottowel

I'm working with the Hot Towel Template and I'm trying to use the gridstack-angular package. I'm basically trying to add the demo functionality into my-page.controller.js, my-page.route.js and my-page.html.

I've used bower to load the dependencies and added 'gridstack-angular' to  core.module.js. Here's where things break in my-page.html:

```
<section id="my-page-view" class="content">
<section class="matter">
    <div container-fluid>
        <h1>gridstack-angular demo</h1>
        <p>{{vm.widgets}}</p>
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.addWidget()" href="#">Add Widget</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div gridstack class="grid-stack grid1" options="vm.options" on-change="vm.onChange(event,items)" on-drag-start="vm.onDragStart(event,ui)"
                     on-drag-stop="vm.onDragStop(event,ui)" on-resize-start="vm.onResizeStart(event,ui)" on-resize-stop="vm.onResizeStop(event,ui)">
                    <div gridstack-item ng-repeat="w in vm.widgets" class="grid-stack-item" gs-item-x="w.x" gs-item-y="w.y"
                         gs-item-width="w.width" gs-item-height="w.height" gs-item-autopos="1" on-item-added="vm.onItemAdded(item)" on-item-removed="vm.onItemRemoved(item)">
                        <div class="grid-stack-item-content">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.removeWidget(w)" href="#">remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Inspecting the browser shows that the directive referenced at:

```
<div gridstack ...>
```

cannot find its gridstack controller. The `<p>` and first `<div>` elements load fine. And yes, the includes are referenced as expected in index.html. Chrome gives me a 't.gridstack is not function'. It appears that gridstack-angular uses 2 controllers and a directive as wrappers for gridstack.js and I've been choking on the angular syntax trying to bake these into Hot Towel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit by bower... needed to include jquery and jquery-ui before angular as can be seen in this post: [Control order of source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009439/control-order-of-source-files)